# Passing login details in Iframe using jQuery / PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to integrate zopim dashboard into my admin panel. I would like to have it in my admin panel in some sort of iframe, but I would also like seamless login on page load.

Can that be perhaps achieved with jQuery / PHP?

Here is url to the page I want to use:
- https://dashboard.zopim.com/

I checked stackoverflow + many forums, but haven't found a proper answer how to pass login details trough iframe with jQuery for example...

Comment: you mean that you want to use jQuery to put username/password into fields and submit form?

Comment: Yes I would like to do that on page load or with few seconds delay, if it's possible and how :S

Comment: no, that's not possible because of cross-domain restrictions in browsers, you can't access the content of iframe if it is from different domain that your main page, probably you can make a proxy using PHP, but I would do that only if the final goal worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass information just in 1 direction, from the page to the iframe, using GET parameters in the URL, so the page called in the iframe can get this info

```
   <iframe src="http://mysite.com?info1=foo&info2=bar" />
```

however you cannot access information of the iframe from the parent page calling that other site.